# Invariant obstructions to gluing Galois representations on elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$, or another separably closed field of characteristic $p$. Let $K$ be the function field of $E$, and let $K_p$ be the local field at a point.

Given a representation of $\operatorname{Gal}(K)$, I can restrict it to a representation of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_p)$ for each $p$. But the group law makes each point isomorphic, so $K_p$ and $\operatorname{Gal}(K_p)$ for each $p$ are isomorphic, so I want to sum up all the local terms for each $p$. To make this a finite sum I'm going to ignore the trivial (=unramified) representations of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_p)$.

Then I linearize by taking the Grothendieck groups of each category. So I get a map from the Grothendieck group of representations of $\operatorname{Gal}(K)$ to the Grothendieck group of representations of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_p)$ modulo the trivial representation. The map sends a representation to the sum of its local factors.

> What is the cokernel of this map?

In other words, I want to know the obstructions to gluing local Galois representations to global ones if I'm allowed to, add, subtract, and translate them.

This came up in my research. I was able to route around it, but I still think the question is interesting.

Comment: What happens in genus 0?

Comment: The paper Local-to-Global extensions of representations of Fundamental groups Nick Katz, implies that for any point on $\mathbb P^1$ and any local Galois representation there, and any other point, you can extend it to a global Galois representation which is unramified everywhere from the other point, where it is tamely ramified. So everything is equivalent to a tame representation. You can move tame representations around freely even without using the $PGL_2$ action.

Comment: Then for tame representations you can reduce to the case of $1$-dimensional representations, where the gluing condition is that if you multiply together all the local representation it's trivial. So essentially the determinant map is the cokernel.

Comment: Doesn't pulling back representations from $\mathbb P^1$ to $E$ show that the difference between the two cases is 2-torsion? Or maybe an upper bound of 2 copies of the determinant plus 2-torsion?

Comment: @BenWieland  if you just use a double cover than you get one copy of the representation plus one copy of the representation pulled back along the inverse map. So you do get V + inverse V = 2 det ( V), but I don't immediately see 2-torsion. Maybe from other maps you can get more relations?